# Grouped UITableView in NativeScript-Vue

Tags: ios, uitableview, nativescript, nativescript-vue

How do I create a grouped table using a `UITableView` in NativeScript-vue, so that it might look like the iOS settings app, or [this screenshot from the apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/images/Tables_Grouped.png). I need to support having switches in the table cells. I want to create this style using as many native styles as possible and also be compatible with android. I have tried applying NativeScript UI classes to `Label`s in a `StackLayout` with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Sectioned list view is a iOS specific feature and there is a [plugin](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-sectioned-list-view). But if you like a cross platform solution, [create 2 templates](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/list-view#using-multiple-item-templates) and style one like section header and another with simple labels / switches etc.,